# Background Excel and VBA

Tags: excel

I am new to VBA, I have a excel file with completely white background, 
How can I change in to normal Excel format with default gridlines (not the borders)

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a VBA issue. I think you're looking for the option "Gridlines" in the "View" tab?

Comment: In `Home` menu ->`Font` group, select `No Border`.

Comment: Select area, then Home tab -> Editing part -> Clear -> Clear formats

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to change the edges of the cell, 
You can do this as follows with the LineStyle property.

Example:

```
Range("A26:A27").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'modified edge style
Range("A26:A27").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone       'delete edge
Range("A26").Interior.ColorIndex = 19             'change cell color
Range("A26").Font.Bold = True                     'put text in bold
Range("A26").Value = "Example text"
```